# For loop with array doesn't work with innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I have a div with the `ID="ranking"` and I'd like to put there some info of a JavaScript array with a table where every row has tow columns: one for `dados[i][25]` and other for `dados[i][26]`.

My code is this:

```
function dadosRanking(dados){
        document.getElementById("ranking").innerHTML += '<table class="table"><tr><td valign="middle" class="question" colspan=2><h1>RANKING (+ PONTOS)</h1></td></tr><tr><td>PONTOS</td><td>UTILIZADOR</td></tr>'
        for(var i=1;i<6;i++)
        {
          document.getElementById("ranking").innerHTML += '<tr><td>' + dados[i][25] + '</td><td>' + dados[i][26] + '</td></tr>';
        }
        document.getElementById("ranking").innerHTML += '</table>';
}
```

The code I expect was this:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" class="question" colspan=2>
      <h1>RANKING (+ PONTOS)</h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>PONTOS</td>
    <td>UTILIZADOR</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      100
    </td>
    <td>
      Username
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, the HTML code script write is this:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td valign="middle" class="question" colspan=2>
      <h1>RANKING (+ PONTOS)</h1>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>PONTOS</td>
    <td>UTILIZADOR</td>
  </tr>
</table>
"100Username"
```

Comment: Is there any other section in your code that references the `ranking` element?

Comment: No. The only references of ranking are the ones that I wrote here.

Comment: @LittleSanti not sure if you missed it but I posted an answer 20 minutes ago.

Comment: @Halcyon Yes, just a few minutes ago. I liked it and upvoted it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everytime you update `innerHTML` the browser will parse it and render it, to do that it will also try to 'fix' your HTML. This can have unintended consequences. Instead of pushing to `innerHTML` with a partial table definition, collect the HTML in a separate value and push to `innerHTML` once.

```
function dadosRanking(dados){
    var s = "";
    s += '<table class="table"><tr><td valign="middle" class="question" colspan=2><h1>RANKING (+ PONTOS)</h1></td></tr><tr><td>PONTOS</td><td>UTILIZADOR</td></tr>'
    for(var i=1;i<6;i++) {
        s += '<tr><td>' + dados[i][25] + '</td><td>' + dados[i][26] + '</td></tr>';
    }
    s += '</table>';
    document.getElementById("ranking").innerHTML += s;
}
```

After

```
document.getElementById("ranking").innerHTML += '<table class="table"><tr><td valign="middle" class="question" colspan=2><h1>RANKING (+ PONTOS)</h1></td></tr><tr><td>PONTOS</td><td>UTILIZADOR</td></tr>'
```

innerHTML becomes:

```
<table class="table">
  <tr><td valign="middle" class="question" colspan=2><h1>RANKING (+ PONTOS)</h1></td></tr>
  <tr><td>PONTOS</td><td>UTILIZADOR</td></tr>
</table>
```

Note that the table has been closed!

After

```
document.getElementById("ranking").innerHTML += '<tr><td>foo</td><td>bar</td></tr>';
```

innerHTML becomes

```
<table>..</table>
foobar
```

`<tr>` and `<td>` are not valid outside of a table context so they're removed.

After

```
document.getElementById("ranking").innerHTML += '</table>';
```

innerHTML doesn't change because `</table>` doesn't do anything, there is no table to close.